# How to create a MySQLi_prep function

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which works great for the earlier PHP versions where mysql_connect was being used. Does anyone know how to edit this to work with the new mysqli functions? Or similarly do you know of any other functions that do the job just as well.

```
function mySQLiReady( $value ) {
    $magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $new_enough_php = function_exists( "mysql_real_escape_string" ); // i.e. PHP >= v4.3.0
    if( $new_enough_php ) { // PHP v4.3.0 or higher
        // undo any magic quote effects so mysql_real_escape_string can do the work
        if( $magic_quotes_active ) { 
            $value = stripslashes( $value ); 
        }
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string( $value );
    } else { // before PHP v4.3.0
        // if magic quotes aren't already on then add slashes manually
        if( !$magic_quotes_active ) { 
            $value = addslashes( $value ); 
        }
        // if magic quotes are active, then the slashes already exist
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: 1) You should never be using `addslashes` when interacting with a database. 2) If using mySQli, you should not use MYSQL_* functions.

Comment: Why shouldnt I use addslashes? I know that I cant use MySQL functions with MySQLi

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: `mySQLiReady` comes to the conclusion that you opened the database connection with [`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php). In any case, you shouldn't be using `addslashes`. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) instead.

Comment: Just use prepared statements and forget about the whole escaping thing: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: And run away screaming from any servers that only have php < 5 installed...

Comment: You don't really need any of that stuff with prepared statements.

Comment: Instead of wasting your time with this, learn how to work with `PDO` and prepared statements. You will save yourself a lot of time and will make your queries a lot safer. Also, with `PDO` you can convert your application to a different DB (i.e. PostgreSQL, Oracle and etc) in a glance.

Comment: @user1281385 if possible i would like to stay away from prepared statements since I cant echo out the sql statement for debugging. Or is there a way around that?

Comment: @tftd I looked into it before but as i said before the main problem is not being able to echo out a SQL statement then to help with debugging

Comment: That's not exactly true. I use a class that extends `PDO` and throws a custom exception. The exception holds the failed query and from there I print that out.

Comment: @tftd is that available online anywhere? To be honest thats the only reason I havent moved forward to PDO yet

Comment: No, it's not available because it's a custom class but I could post an example if you'd like?

Comment: @tftd if you didnt mind that would be great, im learning PDO from a Novice to Ninja book and the exceptions are confusing me a bit.

Comment: @tftd would you be able to show me how I could go about building that custom class?

Comment: yeah, I'll post it in a half an hour

Comment: What kind of answer is this? Looks like a comment to me, or spam...

Comment: The questions were: " Does anyone know how to edit this to work with the new mysqli functions? Or similarly do you know of any other functions that do the job just as well." - you don't understand how "you don't need any of that code" is answering those questions?

Comment: No, i'm afraid i don't understand that... This does not look like an answer to me.

Comment: Cool. It wasnt marked as the answer so what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// lib/DatabaseException.php
<?php

namespace Database;

/**
 * Class DatabaseException
 * This is the exception class that will be thrown whenever a PDOException occurs.
 * The exception will have the prepared statement with the values inside.
 *
 * @package  Database
 */
class DatabaseException extends \PDOException {

    protected $sql_code = null;

    /**
     *
     * @param string             $message
     * @param null               $sql_code
     * @param null               $prepare
     * @param null|\PDOException $previous_exception
     */
    public function __construct($message = "", $sql_code = null, $prepare = null, \PDOException $previous_exception = null){
        if(is_array($prepare)){
            foreach($prepare as $key => $value) {
                $sql_code = str_replace($key, "'".addslashes($value)."'", $sql_code);
            }
        }
        $this->sql_code = $sql_code;
        parent::__construct($message.$this->getTrace()." --- \n [ Query: [  ".$this->sql_code."  ] ]", ($previous_exception && is_int($previous_exception->getCode()) ? $previous_exception->getCode() : 0));
    }
}
?>


// lib/QueryStatement.php
<?php

namespace Database;

/**
 * Class QueryStatement
 * This class's purpose is to extend \PDOStatement, save the prepared statement's data
 * and trigger DatabaseException exceptions on errors.
 *
 * @package Database
 */
class QueryStatement extends \PDOStatement {

    /**
     * This variable holds all of the bindParam/bindColumn/bindValue values
     * @var array
     */
    protected $values = array();

    protected function __construct() {
        // Set the default fetch mode to \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        $this->setFetchMode( \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    }

    /**
     * Overwrite the default \PDOStatement::bindParam so that the param & variables are stored in $this->values
     *
     * @param mixed $parameter
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param int   $data_type
     *
     * @return bool|void
     * @throws DatabaseException
     */
    public function bindValue($parameter, $value, $data_type = \PDO::PARAM_STR){
        try {
            $this->values[$parameter] = $value;
            parent::bindValue($parameter, $value, $data_type);
        } catch(\PDOException $e) {
            throw new DatabaseException($e->getMessage(), $this->queryString, $this->values, $e);
        }
    }

    public function execute(array $input_parameters = null){
        try {
            if($input_parameters != null)
                $this->values = array_merge($input_parameters, $this->values);
            parent::execute($input_parameters);
        } catch(\PDOException $e) {
            throw new DatabaseException($e->getMessage(), $this->queryString, $this->values, $e);
        }
    }

}

?>


// lib/Database.php
<?php

namespace Database;

require_once('DatabaseException.php');
require_once('QueryStatement.php');

use Database\QueryStatement;
use Database\DatabaseException;

/**
 * Class Database
 * This is a wrapper class - it's like a proxy to the default PDO methods, but
 * the methods have a try/catch block. In case a PDOException is thrown, this will
 * trigger a DatabaseException where the prepared query will be visible with the
 * prepared values.
 *
 * @package Database
 */
class Database extends \PDO {

    /**
     * Initialize database connection
     *
     * @param $dsn
     * @param $user (optional - in some drivers you can define the user&pass within the dsn string)
     * @param $pass (optional - in some drivers you can define the user&pass within the dsn string)
     *
     * @throws DatabaseException
     */
    public function __construct( $dsn, $user = null, $pass = null ) {
        if ( $dsn ) {
            try {
                parent::__construct( $dsn, $user, $pass );
                $this->setAttribute( \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                $this->setAttribute( \PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('Database\QueryStatement', array($this)) );
            } catch ( \PDOException $e ) {
                throw new DatabaseException( "Could not connect to db!", 'Not available!', null, $e );
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new DatabaseException( 'Connection to database cannot be established! Missing parameters!' );
        }
    }

    public function prepare($statement, array $driver_options = array()){
        try {
            return parent::prepare( $statement, $driver_options );
        } catch ( \PDOException $e ) {
            throw new DatabaseException( $e->getMessage(), $statement, null, $e );
        }
    }

    public function exec($statement){
        try {
            return parent::exec( $statement );
        } catch ( \PDOException $e ) {
            throw new DatabaseException( $e->getMessage(), $statement, null, $e );
        }
    }
}


?>
```

And this is an example usage:

```
// a_script_that_uses_db_connection.php
<?php

// Example usage.
require_once('lib/Database.php');
use Database\Database;

/**
 * Enter a valid DSN connection string. The strings for all supported databases
 * can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php
 *
 * Most used DSN strings
 *
 * MySQL DSN string:
 * mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=testdb
 * OR
 * mysql:unix_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock;dbname=testdb
 * (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)
 *
 * PostgreSQL DSN string:
 * pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=testdb;user=bruce;password=mypass
 * (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php)
 *
 * SQLite DSN string:
 * sqlite:/opt/databases/mydb.sq3
 * sqlite::memory:
 * sqlite2:/opt/databases/mydb.sq2
 * sqlite2::memory:
 * (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php)
 *
 */
$connect_string = "pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;port=5432;dbname=testing_database";
$db = new Database($connect_string, 'my_username', 'my_password');

// Create a prepared statement
$ps = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username');
$ps->bindValue(':username', 'admin');
$ps->execute();
$ps->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// An invalid query (i.e. the query throws PDOException)
$ps = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE usernamee = :username');
$ps->bindValue(':username', 'admin');
$ps->execute();
$ps->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// The result will be a DatabaseException with the following message
// Database\DatabaseException: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "usernamee" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM users WHERE usernamee = $1 ^ --- [ Query: [ SELECT * FROM users WHERE usernamee = 'admin' ] ] in /path/to/lib/QueryStatement.php on line 51
// and a stack trace which will show you exactly where the query was executed.

?>
```

Pretty much this is a wrapper class that extends the `PDO` class. In case a `PDOException` is `thrown` in a prepared statement, a new `DatabaseException` with the actual query.

You can clone the code with git from [here](https://github.com/steve-todorov/php-pdo-wrapper)

Hope this helps you and all other devs trying to figure this out.